# Merging IntelliJ tasks with no-ff

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I love IntelliJ tasks for simplifying my workflow. However, when I close a task and check `merge with branche(s)`, it merge's my feature branch without `no-ff`.

How can I enable `no-ff` with IntelliJ tasks?

Answer (score 0):

If you can work with fast-forward merges in Git globally, then [the following solution](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99115#focus=Comments-27-3267224.0-0) may be better because it applies to all projects:

> It seems as if IntelliJ does honour global configuration values.
> Having set this, upon performing a merge it creates a proper merge
> commit, even when performing the merge from the UI. It even displays a
> popup offering to delete the source branch.
>
> ```
> $ git config --global --add merge.ff false
> ```

##### From the [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#ac91b34c) documentation (since 2020.2):

> If you need to specify merge options, from the main menu choose **VCS
> Git | Merge Changes** to open the **Merge** dialog:
>
> [image: The Merge dialog]
>
> Select the branch that you want to merge into the current branch,
> click **Modify Options** and choose from the following:
>
> - --no-ff: a merge commit will be created in all cases, even if the merge could be resolved as a fast-forward.
> - --ff-only: the merge will be resolved only if it is possible to fast-forward.
> - --squash: a single commit with all pulled changes will be created on top of the current branch.
> - -m: you will be able to edit the message for the merge commit.
> - --no-commit: a merge will be performed, but a merge commit will not be created so that you can inspect the result of the merge before
>   committing.
>
> Click **Merge.**

---

##### 2019 version does have a merge menu also:

<kbd>VCS</kbd> > <kbd>Git</kbd> > <kbd>Merge Changes...</kbd>

[image: merge menu]